# Insert Error during unit test on Opportunity trigger

Tags: trigger, unit-test

I'm running tests on a trigger I've created and can't figure out why the following error is being produced.

**Error: System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION,  Not a valid gift certificate. Either gift certificate with that code does not exist or the balance is $0: []**

To explain this error a little more, the text "Not a valid gift certificate..." above is an intentional error I created in the trigger (code below) to prevent users from creating opportunities with the codes of gift certificates that are not valid or don't have a balance.

All of the records that I'm inserting in the test class, however, reference a gift certificate code of a valid gift certificate with ample funds. I'm trying to figure out why this piece of code is being called and I'm stuck. Any help would be appreciated.

Trigger

```
trigger GiftCertDonation on Opportunity (after insert, after update) {

//If this is an update, check to see if there's a gift certificate that was already debited.
set<id> doNotProcess = new set<id>();
if (trigger.isUpdate){
    for(Opportunity oldDonation : trigger.old) {
        if (oldDonation.Gift_Certificate__c != null){
            doNotProcess.add(oldDonation.id);
        }
    }
}

//SOQL to return a list of gift certificates whose balance is greater than zero
list<Journal_Gift_Card_Usages__c> giftcertlist = [SELECT id, Gift_Card__r.id, Gift_Card__r.Gift_Certificate_Code__c, Balance__c FROM Journal_Gift_Card_Usages__c WHERE Balance__c > 0];

//Convert the list into two maps - one with the gc code and jgcu id, the other with gc code and gc balance
map<string, id> jgcuMap = new map<string, id>();
map<string, decimal> balanceMap = new map<string, decimal>();
for (Journal_Gift_Card_Usages__c g :giftcertlist){
    jgcuMap.put(g.Gift_Card__r.Gift_Certificate_Code__c, g.id);
    balanceMap.put(g.Gift_Card__r.Gift_Certificate_Code__c, g.Balance__c);
}

//declared list of Gift Cart Usages to later insert 
list<Gift_Card_Usage__c> lstgcusToInsert = new List<Gift_Card_Usage__c>();

//declared list of Opportunities to later insert
list<Opportunity> oppsToUpdate = new List<Opportunity>();

//declare the gcamount variable to be assigned later
decimal gcamount;

for (Opportunity o : trigger.new){

    //Has this opportunity already created a gift card usage? 
    if (doNotProcess.contains(o.id)){
        return;
    }

        //Determine if the opportunity in question has a gift certificate as one of the payment methods?
    else if (((o.Pay_Method__c == 'Gift Certificate') || (o.Pay_Method__c == 'Multiple Methods' && (o.Multiple_Methods_1__c == 'Gift Certificate' || o.Multiple_Methods_2__c == 'Gift Certificate' ))) && o.createdById != '005G0000001cbVV' ){

        //Does the gift certifiacte code refer to a gift certificate with a 
        if (jgcuMap.containsKey(o.Gift_Certificate__c)){

            //Depending on the payment method, set the gcamount
            if (o.Pay_Method__c == 'Gift Certificate'){
                gcamount = o.Amount ;
            }
            else if (o.Multiple_Methods_1__c == 'Gift Certificate'){
                gcamount = o.Multiple_Methods_Amount_1__c ;
            }
            else if (o.Multiple_Methods_2__c == 'Gift Certificate'){
                gcamount = o.Multiple_Methods_Amount_2__c ; 
            }

            //Create New Gift Card Usage
            Gift_Card_Usage__c gcu = new Gift_Card_Usage__c();
            gcu.Journal_Gift_Card_Usages__c = jgcuMap.get(o.Gift_Certificate__c) ;
            if ((balanceMap.get(o.Gift_Certificate__c) - gcamount) < 0){
                gcu.Amount_Used__c = balanceMap.get(o.Gift_Certificate__c);
            }
            else {
                gcu.Amount_Used__c = gcamount;
                }

            //add to list
            lstgcusToInsert.add(gcu);

            }

        else {
            o.addError(' Not a valid gift certificate. Either gift certificate with that code does not exist or the balance is $0');
        }   
    }
}

if(lstgcusToInsert.size() > 0) {
    insert lstgcusToInsert;
}

if(oppsToUpdate.size() > 0){
    update oppsToUpdate;
}
```

}

TestClass

```
@isTest
private class GiftCertTriggerTest {
    static testMethod void MyUnitTest(){                

            //Gift Cert as pay method
            Opportunity opp1 = new Opportunity();
            opp1.name = 'Test 1';
            opp1.RecordType = [SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE SObjectType = 'Opportunity' and Name = 'Single Donation'];
            opp1.Type = 'Individual Gift';
            opp1.Amount = 10;
            opp1.CloseDate = system.today();
            opp1.StageName = 'Received';
            opp1.Pay_Method__c = 'Gift Certificate';
            opp1.Gift_Certificate__c = '6127225559';

            //Gift Cert as Multiple Method 1
            Opportunity opp2 = new Opportunity();
            opp2.name = 'Test 2';
            opp2.RecordType = [SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE SObjectType = 'Opportunity' and Name = 'Single Donation'];
            opp2.Type = 'Individual Gift';
            opp2.Amount = 15;
            opp2.CloseDate = system.today();
            opp2.StageName = 'Received';
            opp2.Pay_Method__c = 'Multiple Methods';
            opp2.Multiple_Methods_Amount_1__c = 10;
            opp2.Multiple_Methods_1__c = 'Gift Certificate';
            opp2.Multiple_Methods_Amount_2__c = 5;
            opp2.Multiple_Methods_2__c = 'Cash';
            opp2.Gift_Certificate__c = '6127225559';

                //Gift Cert as Multiple Method 2
            Opportunity opp3 = new Opportunity();
            opp3.name = 'Test 3';
            opp3.RecordType = [SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE SObjectType = 'Opportunity' and Name = 'Single Donation'];
            opp3.Type = 'Individual Gift';
            opp3.Amount = 15;
            opp3.CloseDate = system.today();
            opp3.StageName = 'Received';
            opp3.Pay_Method__c = 'Multiple Methods';
            opp3.Multiple_Methods_Amount_1__c = 5;
            opp3.Multiple_Methods_1__c = 'Cash';
            opp3.Multiple_Methods_Amount_2__c = 10;
            opp3.Multiple_Methods_2__c = 'Gift Certificate';
            opp3.Gift_Certificate__c = '6127225559';

            //Opportunity with Gift Cert that has already been debited.

            list<Opportunity> oppsToInsert = new list<Opportunity>();
            oppsToInsert.add(opp1);
            oppsToInsert.add(opp2);
            oppsToInsert.add(opp3);

            //Testing 
            Test.startTest();
            insert oppsToInsert;
            Test.stopTest();


    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not too sure but the reason why your code is throwing the error could be: 
1) jgcuMap is empty
Why is it empty?
Because when u say in your test class

```
        opp2.Gift_Certificate__c = '6127225559';
        opp1.Gift_Certificate__c = '6127225559';
        opp3.Gift_Certificate__c = '6127225559';
```

I see that you are adding in your code

```
jgcuMap.put(g.Gift_Card__r.Gift_Certificate_Code__c, g.id);
```

In you test class you are not creating a gift_card__c record :
before creating the opps do

```
Journal_Gift_Card_Usages__c gift = new Journal_Gift_Card_Usages__c();
gift.allrequiredfields;
gift.Gift_Certificate_Code__c = '6127225559';
insert gift;
```

and then

```
    opp2.Gift_Certificate__c = gift.Gift_Certificate_Code__c;
    opp1.Gift_Certificate__c = gift.Gift_Certificate_Code__c;
    opp3.Gift_Certificate__c = gift.Gift_Certificate_Code__c;
```

Comment: Thanks, rao! I'll give that a try and let you know how it works out.

Comment: @dannymorty any luck, were u able to get the error resolved?

Comment: No luck yet. The issue is that in order a new Journal_Gift_Card_Usages__c record, I actually have to create a Journal__c record which kicks off a trigger that i turn creates a Journal_Gift_Card_Usages__c. When inserting that Journal__c record, I receive an error:  System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, Journal: execution of AfterInsert

caused by: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object

Class.Journal.afterInsert: line 61, column 1
Trigger.Journal: line 5, column 1: []

Comment: I've followed the error back to line 61 on the appropriate trigger but can't figure out how it's related to my code. I'm digging in some more.

Comment: I think its more a cascading effect!!! There must be some kind of a list that must be empty when the Journal__c  is being created. LMK if i can be of any help here :)

Comment: Hey @Rao, thanks for your help. I located the offending code but am having difficulty resolving the issue. It seems somewhat of a different issue so I created a new question for it. You can find it [here.](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/7656/soql-query-produces-different-result-with-same-input) Thanks for all your help up to now.

Comment: My other issues were caused by not creating the rest of my data in the test specifically. Using the SeeAllData = True solved the subsequent issues I was having. Anyone can have a look [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_annotation_isTest.htm) if they want to see more about that. Again, @Rao, thanks for your help!